# Bacon.js restart buffering when another EventStream fires

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, bacon.js

I'm trying to make a simple canvas-drawing app using Bacon.js. It should allow to draw a line by selecting start and end point using mouse clicks like this.

```
points = paper.asEventStream('click')
  .map((e) -> x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY)
  .bufferWithCount(2)
```

So far so good. Now it should allow to cancel starting point selection by clicking Esc.

```
cancel = doc.asEventStream('keypress')
  .map((e) -> e.keyCode)
  .filter((key) -> key is 27)
  .map(true)
```

What is the baconian way of restarting buffering?
**UPD:** The implementation I've got so far looks awful.

```
points
  .merge(cancel)
  .buffer(undefined, (buffer) ->
    values = buffer.values
    if values.some((val) -> val is true) then values.length = 0
    else if values.length is 2 then buffer.flush())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the buffering from cancel:

```
var filteredPairs = cancel.startWith(true).flatMapLatest(function() {
  return points.bufferWithCount(2)
})
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9qdrjddy/1/)